# Project Links in JIRA Text Markup

Tags: jira

Is there a way to create a link in a JIRA text field to a JIRA project without specifying the fully qualified URL for that project?

For instance, if I want to link to a JIRA issue in a JIRA text field, I can simply type the issue identifier (eg: FOO-1234) and the rendered text will produce a link to that specific issue.  I'm looking for something similar for the project itself rather than individual issues.

The [text formatting help for links](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=links) mentions neither issue linking nor project linking, so I'm hoping there's an undocumented feature for project linking as exists for issue linking.

Comment: I've also looked for this in the JIRA documentation.  Doesn't appear to be supported at this time.  If you really want this ability it may be worth logging a feature request at https://jira.atlassian.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this would really require creating a custom renderer for a field with an add-on. Or you could use a project picker custom field perhaps